# Proof that [0,1] is compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Is this a valid proof that $K=[0,1]$ is compact?

Suppose we had a open cover $\{G_a\}$ of $K$ that did not give a finite subcover. We split $[0,1]$ into $[0,1/2]$ and $[1/2,1]$. At least one of these intervals cannot be covered by a finite subcover of $\{G_a\}$, call it $I_1$. Next divide $I_1$ in half similarly to obtain $I_2$. Continue doing this to obtain $I_1 \supset I_2 \supset I_3...$, and by construction any $I_n$ cannot be covered by a finite subcover of $\{G_a\}$. We know that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n$ contains some element $x$ (it is the supremum the $a_n$ where $I_n =[a_n,b_n]$). Then $x \in G_a$ for some $a$ and $G_a$ is open so there exists a neighborhood  $N_r(x) \subset G_a$ but then (by the Archimedean property of the reals) there exists large enough $n$ such that $2^{-n}<r$ and then for any $y\in I_n$ we know $|x-y|\leq 2^{-n}<r$ and $I_n \subset G_a$ contradicting that no $I_n$ can be covered by a finite subcover of $\{G_a\}$.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: The proof technique was then used by Walter Rudin to show that $k$-cells are compact. $k$-cells are $k$-cartesian products of finite intervals, residing as a subset of  $\mathbb R^k$. Indeed, the same kind of compactness could probably work in a topological space with order, where the topology respects the order in some way.